# Extended KeywordModel with metadata fails when metadata empty

Tags: dxa, web8.5, dxa-java, dxa-2.0

This is the metadata schema that we have linked to a keyword

```
@Data
@SemanticEntity(entityName = "HotelMeta", vocabulary = SDL_CORE)
public class HotelKeyword extends KeywordModel {
        @JsonIgnore
        private List<KeywordModel> nearbyHotels;
}
```

"name": {
                            "$type": "KeywordModelData",
                            "Id": "5228",
                            "Description": "Hotel F",
                            "Key": "FAR",
                            "TaxonomyId": "124",
                            "Title": "Hotel F",
                            "SchemaId": "10872",
                            "Metadata": {
                                "nearbyHotel": {
                                    "$type": "KeywordModelData[]",
                                    "$values": [
                                        {
                                            "Id": "624",
                                            "Description": "Rad Keni",
                                            "Key": "GBKE",
                                            "TaxonomyId": "124",
                                            "Title": "Rad Keni",
                                            "Metadata": {}
                                        },
                                        {
                                            "Id": "620",
                                            "Description": "Rd Man",
                                            "Key": "rd man",
                                            "TaxonomyId": "124",
                                            "Title": "Rd Man",
                                            "Metadata": {}
                                        }
                                    ]
                                }
                            }
                        },

But when metadata is not informed we've got an Exception

"name": {
                            "$type": "KeywordModelData",
                            "Id": "620",
                            "Description": "Rad Man",
                            "Key": "rad man",
                            "TaxonomyId": "124",
                            "Title": "Rad Man",
                            "Metadata": {}
                        }

```
Error:

java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can not set com.dxa.modules.entities.hotel.HotelKeyword field com.dxa.modules.entities.hotel.Hotel.name to com.sdl.webapp.common.api.model.KeywordModel

                at sun.reflect.UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.throwSetIllegalArgumentException(UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.java:167)
                at sun.reflect.UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.throwSetIllegalArgumentException(UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.java:171)
                at sun.reflect.UnsafeObjectFieldAccessorImpl.set(UnsafeObjectFieldAccessorImpl.java:81)
                at java.lang.reflect.Field.set(Field.java:764)
                at com.sdl.webapp.common.impl.mapping.SemanticMapperImpl$1.doWith(SemanticMapperImpl.java:144)
                at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.doWithFields(ReflectionUtils.java:693)
                at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.doWithFields(ReflectionUtils.java:673)
                at com.sdl.webapp.common.impl.mapping.SemanticMapperImpl.createEntity(SemanticMapperImpl.java:105)
                at com.sdl.dxa.tridion.mapping.impl.DefaultModelBuilder.createViewModel(DefaultModelBuilder.java:157)
                at com.sdl.dxa.tridion.mapping.impl.DefaultModelBuilder.buildEntityModel(DefaultModelBuilder.java:123)
                at com.sdl.dxa.tridion.mapping.impl.ModelBuilderPipelineImpl.createEntityModel(ModelBuilderPipelineImpl.java:86)
                at com.dxa.modules.entities.EntityLoader.loadEntityModel(EntityLoader.java:64)
                at com.dxa.modules.entities.EntityLoader.loadPageModelEntity(EntityLoader.java:59)
                at com.dxa.modules.entities.AnotherEntitiesIT.should_load_hotel_from_static_page(AnotherEntitiesIT.java:34)
                at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
                at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
                at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
                at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
                at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
                at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
                at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
                at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:26)
                at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.java:75)
                at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.java:86)
                at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.SpringRepeat.evaluate(SpringRepeat.java:84)
                at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
                at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:252)
                at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:94)
                at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
                at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
                at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
                at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
                at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
                at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
                at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:70)
                at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
                at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:191)
                at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
                at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:68)
                at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:47)
                at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:242)
                at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:70)

13:20:04.714 [Thread-1] INFO  o.s.w.c.s.GenericWebApplicationContext - Closing org.springframework.web.context.support.GenericWebApplicationContext@482cd91f: startup date [Fri Jul 13 13:19:40 CEST 2018]; root of context hierarchy
```

**UPDATE**
This error happens not only in our tests but also when running the web app

This is java Entity Class Hotel which has HotelKeyword attribute with name “name”

```
@Data
@SemanticEntity(entityName = "Hotel", vocabulary = SDL_CORE)
public class Hotel extends AbstractEntityModel {

    //General
    private Text text;
    private ContactInfo contactInfo;

    //Metadata
    @SemanticProperty("tripadvisor")
    private String tripAdvisorCode;
    private HotelKeyword name;
    private Tag brand;
    private Tag city;
    private Tag state;
}
```

In line 144 of the log, it's trying to map the information of the attribute name of the hotel entity, but it fails to do so because it expects a field in the metadata called nearby, this happens only when the keyword doesn’t have this metadata field

Comment: Looking at the Stack Trace, it seems this exception occurred while running a unit test. Do you observe the same problem in the web application?

Answer (score 1):

The exception happens on line 144 in this file: https://github.com/sdl/dxa-web-application-java/blob/release/2.0/dxa-framework/dxa-common-api/src/main/java/com/sdl/webapp/common/impl/mapping/SemanticMapperImpl.java

I’m trying to make sense out of the exception message, but I don’t understand it. Apparently, it tries to set a field named `name`, which your View Model Type (`HotelKeyword`) doesn’t have. Not sure why it thinks it should set that property. And what is type `com.dxa.entities.hotel.Hotel` ?

Note that there’s trace output happening (e.g. line 137). Maybe a log file with log level set to TRACE can shed some light?

**UPDATE**

With the additional information provided, the exception message starts making sense to me:  it just says that it is unable to set your `Hotel.name` property to an object of type `KeywordModel`, which makes sense, because the property is more strongly typed than that (it's of type `HotelKeyword`).

I guess this happens in that scenario, because there is no Schema ID in the R2 Data Model, so it can't use Semantic Mapping to determine a specific View Model Type to use and hence instantiates a generic `KeywordModel`.

This is indeed defective, because it could/should have determined the View Model Type from your `Hotel.name` property type.

Does this problem occur in general, or only for dynamically expanded Keyword Models?

As a work-around, would it be possible to make the `Hotel.name` property more loosely typed (let its type be `KeywordModel`), so that you don't hit this exception.  If all is well, it will still instantiate a `HotelKeyword` in case a Schema ID (and metadata) is present.  In case it is not present, you won't have any additional metadata to map anyways, so a generic `KeywordModel` should be sufficient.

Comment: I added more comments. We think we found a new bug in the product.

Comment: Ah, now I get it. I have updated my answer.  Seems like bug, indeed, but hopefully with a work-around possible.

Comment: I don't get it. It's not that the Hotel.name is empty, but when it fails is when Hotel.name.nearbyHotels is empty.

Comment: Based on the R2 JSON you provided, it seems that in the problematic scenario, the CM Keyword doesn’t have metadata (nor a metadata Schema) at all. As a result, there is no Schema ID in the JSON and as a result of that, the semantic mapping logic gets confused and instantiates  `KeywordModel` instead of `HotelKeyword`.